# How do we return a Promise from a store.dispatch in Redux - saga so that we can wait for the resolve and then render in SSR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying React SSR using Redux and Redux-saga.

I am able to get the Client Rendering to work but the server store never seems to get the data / wait for the data before rendering the HTML.

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import renderer from "./helpers/renderer";
import createStore from "./helpers/createStore";
import {matchRoutes} from 'react-router-config';
import Routes from "./client/Routes";
import rootSaga from "./client/saga";


const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const store = createStore();
    const branch = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path);
    const promises = branch.map(({ route }) => {
        return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : Promise.resolve(null);
    });
    store.runSaga(rootSaga).done.then(() => {
        res.send(renderer(req, store)) // helper method to load static router and provider  
    }) // Not required after Update 2 , Promise.All should work .. 
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
})
```

**small saga**

```
import { put, takeEvery, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {FETCH_USERS, SAVE_USERS} from "../actions";
import axios from 'axios';

export function* fetchUsers() {
    const res = yield call(getUsers);
    yield put({ type: SAVE_USERS, payload: res.data});
}


const getUsers = () => {
    const response = axios.get('http://react-ssr-api.herokuapp.com/users');
    return response;
}

export function* actionWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery(FETCH_USERS, fetchUsers)
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        actionWatcher()
    ])
}
```

**error**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at /Users/rahsinwb/Documents/Mine/code/SSR/build/bundle.js:309:39

What am I missing here? Or is there any proven way we can listen to the saga ending? I was thinking my loadData helper in the component with `store.dispatch` for initial action call will return promise but that never works.

**LoadData**

```
const loadData = (store) => {
    store.dispatch({type: FETCH_USERS});
}
```

**Update**

Added this to my index.js File

```
 store.runSaga(rootSaga).toPromise().then(() => {
        branch.map(({ route }) => {
            return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : Promise.resolve(null);
        });
        res.send(renderer(req, store))
    })
```

Now the code compiles without any error but the problem is the saga dispatches an action from loadData method i.e. FetchData, before the fetchData calls the Save_DATA action in the saga mentioned above the call gets cancelled my assumption, and the reducer is left empty which causes the html to not load with data.

> How do we know that the data load is completed for the generator
>   function starting from the action initiated to the action for loading data ?
>   to the reducer as only post that i should render component on the server

**Update2**

Also had checked a [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adobe/redux-saga-promise#including-the-middleware), but for some odd reason it throws regenerator issues but i do-not think a lib is need for such a purpose as i plan on reusing the same saga's for client Redux calls to and want to keep changes separated out .
index.js

```
 console.log(promises); // no promise returned  undefined
   //setTimeout((function() {res.send(renderer(req, store))}), 2000);
   Promise.all(promises).then(
      res.send(renderer(req, store))
   )
```

> Adding Set Timeout helps and i am able to fetch data in server and
>   then render so now the CRUX of the problem is that we need to some how
>   wait for the generator function to resolve then call render.

**Update 3**

Added a way around this problem as an answer but i do-not feel it is the best solve and can be abstract this logic out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at

`.done` getter is deprecated since v1, so `.toPromise()` is the way to listen for a saga resolve

As for waiting sagas to complete, there is a special `END` action that you can dispatch to terminate saga when all its child tasks are complete, causing `store.runSaga(rootSaga).toPromise()` promise to resolve.

When the promise is resolved (meaning that all required data is already there), you should send result HTML received from `renderToString` in response. Notice that server-rendered components aren't really mounted, so `componentDidMount()` method won't be triggered, thus your data won't be fetched twice.

So you can modify your code as follows:

```js
// server.js
...
import { END } from 'redux-saga';

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const store = createStore();
    const branch = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path);

    store.runSaga(rootSaga).toPromise().then(() => {
        res.send(renderer(req, store))
    });

    // trigger data fetching
    branch.forEach(({ route }) => {
        route.loadData && route.loadData(store)
    });

    // terminate saga
    store.dispatch(END);
});
```

Also, you can follow [this example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/examples/real-world).

Comment: i think this will cause the component to render twice, which i donot want to do . because `store.runSaga(rootSaga).toPromise().then(() => {
        res.send(renderer(req, store))
    });`
this will cause a render and again the trigger of the loaddata will cause another i donot want to follow that approach as re renders are costly and also have problems like when we want to have loading screen etc..

Comment: Why? `renderer` function is invoked only once when `.toPromise()` is resolved. And if you fetch your data in `componentDidMount()` method, it will be ignored during the initial server side render with `renderToString` function.

Comment: In fact, when component is rendered via `renderToString`, you cannot cause its rerender for any reason whatsoever, because it's just a plain string. The only way to do that is to call `renderToString` explicitly one more time.

Comment: Yes i think its my bad, the express server was being called because of the favicon issue which i thought was re render .. silly me . can you please update the comment as part of thew answer . my bad

Comment: Sure. Updated my answer.

Comment: is this the best possible solve for a server sided app . i will be happy if there are any caveats

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find one way to get around this problem ,But this is not that clean of a solution and i do-not want to do it for every loadData method + the saga . I was able to abstract it is there a cleaner way of achieving this as i am still not satisfied with the answer

**loadData in Component**

```
const loadData = (store) => {
    //store.dispatch({type: FETCH_USERS})
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        store.dispatch({type: FETCH_USERS, callback: resolve })
    });
}
```

**Saga**

```
function asyncCallBackUtil(action){
    if (action.callback) {
        action.callback('Done');
    }
}

export function* fetchUsers(action) {
    const res = yield call(getUsers);
    yield put({ type: SAVE_USERS, payload: res.data});
    asyncCallBackUtil(action);
}
```

Now i can use Promise.All as mentioned on the Post

```
Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
    console.log('here',data);
    res.send(renderer(req, store))
})
```

> Is there a cleaner way for this problem as i need to do it for other
>   saga's too .